# mssql on ubuntu 16-04

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Help me to install MSSQL

Error code

```
root@redie:~# apt-get install mssql-server mssql-tools -y
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: For `mssql-tools` you also need to install `unixodbc-dev`. You should really follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-linux-2017). I'm not sure where you got the instructions you have, either, as the documentation creates the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list`; the file is called `msprod.list` not `mssql.list`. I wonder if you're using old documentation or a guide that is based on a non-RTM version.

Answer (score 0):

According [this instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-linux-2017) you should

1. First, add a Microsoft SQL Server Ubuntu repository in list of sources of packages

   ```
   wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
   sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list)"
   ```
2. Then update a list of sources

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. And now, you can install mssql-server

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server
   ```